# A new movie or series where planes float to the ground. Later we see an alien ship hovering over a city

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

The other day on TikTok I saw a video of a "movie." In it a bunch of modern-day people were standing in a city (NYC?) looking up at the sky as various types of human-made aircraft (planes, helicopters, etc.) were were slowly floating down to the ground in-between the buildings.

The only other thing I can remember was a clip of a spaceship hovering over the city.

No amount of searching has brought me back to this video.

Comment: When you say that there were "aircraft" floating to the ground, so you mean human (contemporary) aeroplanes? Was this a normal 2023 Earth city or something set in the future or past? What did the spaceship look like?

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/sksxNaSQ2s0?si=6ZQJe48SV6caQIPK - Downtime (Twilight Zone)?

Comment: Yes it was definitely set in modern times. The city could have been New York but I dont know that for certain..No it wasn't downtime.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"various types of aircraft were slowly floating to the ground"_? Do you mean human aircraft or alien vessels?

Comment: This description reminds me of the pilot episode of _V_ (2009), in which one or more human planes fell out of the sky when the V flying saucers arrived on Earth, hovering over NYC and 28 other cities. Something about the V ships disrupted human aircraft.

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear.  Human made aircraft planes helicopters, etc.  All slowly lowering themselves to the ground in between the buildings.

Comment: Can you rule out _V_ and _Independence Day_? Those are the two most obvious examples that resemble your description.

Comment: The 5th Wave? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JDJj9X0ZAsM

Comment: @LogicDictates - I don't remember planes floating to the ground in either of those films

Comment: @Valorum - Yes, neither is a perfect match, and my guess is they're probably not what the OP is looking for, but they're close enough that I'd prefer for the OP to explicitly rule them out, rather than leaving that as a question mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the mini-series [*Childhood's End*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4146128/) (2015).

You can see the planes landing in the middle of a crowded city street in the trailer below.

Comment: Yes. This is it.  The vid i saw was made using slightly different cuts but, yes this is it. Weird that a google search never brought this up with all the different ways i tried to search it.